# 'As I heard' vs. 'When I heard'

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Which of the following sentences is correct English, and why?

> As I heard that Greenday got a new CD, I went to the store to buy it.
>
> As soon as I heard that Greenday got a new CD, I went to the store to buy it.
>
> When I heard that Greenday got a new CD, I went to the store to buy it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three sentences actually mean three different things.

> As I heard

means '*Because* I heard'.

> As soon as I heard

means that you went to the store the moment you became aware the new CD was out.

> When I heard

is similar to 'as soon as', but implies a less immediate reaction.

Comment: "As I heard" doesn't mean "Because I heard"; at least not in this context.

Comment: @jae: what do you think it means in this context? Certainly the only way I can interpret that sentence so that it remains grammatical is as @ElendilTheTall said.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence doesn't make sense.  Because "as I heard" means the *moment* you heard, as in "as the shot rang out, the whole world seemed to catch their breath".  Or "as the election results came in, the mayor sat down heavily".

So, you wouldn't go to the shop to buy the new Green Day CD *while hearing of its release*; you'd go to the shop *after* hearing of its release, "as son as you heard".

Comment: Actually, "as" has more than one meaning, including *because*. This sort of construction ("As [reason], [result]") is slightly awkward-sounding to modern ears, but it is nevertheless fully grammatical.

Comment: It makes sense, even if it is awkwardly constructed. It would be better to write it 'I went to the store, as I'd heard the new Greenday CD was out.'

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: "as I'd heard"" is not the same as "as I heard".

Comment: It works equally well with 'hear', if you change the other words' tenses. I can see where you're coming from - "The runner left his mark as the gun went off", meaning _as soon as_ - but as Martha says, in this case, as means _because_. It works with the runner example too: "The runner left his mark _because_ the gun went off".